# Getting duplicated data in tests

Tags: java

When I run the following test case:

```
@Test(timeout=1000) public void shape_displayChar2_rot(){
    String layout =
      "b....\n"+
      ".....\n"+
      "....b\n"+
      "";
    String expect = 
      "SHAPE z\n"+
      "height: 5; width: 3; rotation: CW90\n"+
      "..z\n"+
      "...\n"+
      "...\n"+
      "...\n"+
      "z..\n"+
      "";
    char newDC = 'z';
    char dc = getDisplayChar(layout);
    Shape shape = FitIt.makeShape(layout,dc);
    shape.setDisplayChar(newDC);
    shape.rotateCW();
    assertEquals(newDC, shape.getDisplayChar());
    String actual = shape.toString();
    assertEquals(expect,actual);
  }
```

I get the following failure:

```
Expected:
SHAPE z
height: 5; width: 3; rotation: CW90
..z
...
...
...
z..
```

My actual code's result:

```
Actual:
SHAPE z
height: 5; width: 3; rotation: CW90
b....
.....
....b
..z
...
...
...
z..
```

The `String layout` from the above test case is rotated by `rotateCW()` by 90 degrees ClockWise and also changes its character. My question is why am I getting:

```
b....    <<<<----- WHY AM I GETTING THIS ?
.....    <<<<----- WHY AM I GETTING THIS ?
....b    <<<<----- WHY AM I GETTING THIS ?
..z
...
...
...
z..
```

instead of just:

```
    ..z
    ...
    ...
    ...
    z..
```

Code:

import java.util.*;

```
public class CreateShape implements Shape {

    private String layout;
    private int height;
    private int width;
    private char dc;
    private Rotation initialPos;
    private char[][] shape;
    //private char[][] rotatedShape = new char[height][width];// = new char[shape.length][shape[0].length];

    public CreateShape(int height, int width, char dc, char[][] charLayout, String layout) {
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
        this.dc = dc;
        this.shape = charLayout;
        this.layout = layout;
        initialPos = Rotation.CW0;
        //nextPos = Rotation.CW0;
    }

    public Rotation getRotation() {
        return initialPos;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return this.height;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return this.width;
    }

    public char getDisplayChar() {
        return dc;
    }

    public void setDisplayChar(char c) {
        this.dc = c;
        for (int i = 0; i < shape.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < shape[0].length; j++) {
                //if(shape[i][j] == '.')
                //this.newLayout += shape[i][j];
                if (shape[i][j] != '.') {
                    shape[i][j] = c;
                }
            }
            //this.newLayout+="\n";
        }


    }

    public void rotateCW() {

        initialPos = initialPos.next();
        int w = shape.length;
        int h = shape[0].length;

        char[][] swapped = new char[h][w];
        for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < w; j++) {
                swapped[i][j] = shape[w - j - 1][i];
                layout += swapped[i][j];
            }
            layout += "\n";
        }
        height = swapped.length;
        width = swapped[0].length;

    }

    public boolean isFilledAt(int row, int col) {
        if (row < 0 || row >= height || col < 0 || col >= width) {
            throw new FitItException("Oops! Out of bounds!");
        } else {
            for (int r = 0; r <= height; r++) {
                for (int c = 0; c <= width; c++) {
                    if (shape[row][col] == dc) {
                        return true;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "SHAPE " + this.dc + "\n" +
                "height: " + this.height + ";" + " width: " + this.width + "; " + getRotation().toString() + "\n" +
                this.layout;
    }
}
```

class FitIt

```
public class FitIt {
    public static Shape makeShape(String layout, char displayChar) {
        Shape result;
        int height = 0;
        int width = 0;


        Scanner data = new Scanner(layout);

        while (data.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = data.nextLine();
            width = line.length();
            height++;
        }
        char[][] charLayout = new char[height][width];
        Scanner data2 = new Scanner(layout);
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            String line = data2.nextLine();
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {

                if (line.charAt(j) != '.') {
                    charLayout[i][j] = displayChar;
                }
                if (line.charAt(j) == '.') {
                    charLayout[i][j] = line.charAt(j);
                }
            }
        }
        data2.close();
        result = new CreateShape(height, width, displayChar, charLayout, layout);
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: what's your `FitIt.makeShape(layout,dc);`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `rotateCW()` method, you forget to clear the `layout`. You can add `layout = ""` before the for loop and have a try.

Answer (score 3):

When you rotate the text, you are appending the rotated lines to the current layout.

You are not starting from a fresh `String`. So your original layout is preserved in the result.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @TanmayPatil. But why do I have to start with a fresh layout. Does not it overwrite it its new characters withing the frames of the for loop ?

Comment: Use a fresh object, use the same variable to store it. That's what I meant.